# After selecting date flatpickr disappered

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

i have selected timezone from select option after that one date from flatpickr when i click on date my flatpickr disappered. why this problem arries did not get please help.. thank you in advance.

```html
<div class="md:text-right flatPickr">
    <h4 class="mb-2 md:text-left">Book an Appointment</h4>
    <input class="inputhide" type="text" id="basicDate" hidden="true" data-input wire:model.lazy="selectedDate" wire:change="getAvailability"></div>

<script>
    $("#basicDate").flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
        inline: true,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please remove data-input attribute. maybe that cause this issue.

Comment: problem here `hidden="true"` delete this